# Adding images to an edit text view

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, editview

How do I add an image to an edit view in Android Studio something similar to this:

[image]

Where an image view shows up in an edit text view

I've thought of nesting views but that's not an option in Android Studio or embedding a layout inside the edit view every time a picture gets added.

Answer (score 0):

EditText is not a view group but a view, unlike Linear Layout or any other layouts. You can make use of ConstraintLayout and constraint the Image to the EditText.

**OR**

You can add this line to the EditText

```
android:drawableStart="R.drawable.my_image"
```

**OR**

```
android:drawableEnd="R.drawable.my_image"
```